# how to attach multiple ModelAdmins to UserAdmin in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I have a `search model` which has a `ForeignKey` relation to `User`

```
class Searches(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ......
```

I have a `UserProfile` model which has a `OnetoOne` Relationship to `User`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    ispublic=models.NullBooleanField()
```

I have attached `UserProfile` in `admin.py` as follows:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):

    inlines=(UserProfileInline, )
    list_filter = UserAdmin.list_filter + ('email',)
    list_display=('username','email','first_name','last_name','isPublic')


admin.site.unregister(get_user_model())
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), UserProfileAdmin)
```

Now I do not see a separate `UserProfile` but is integrated into `User`, which is what I want.

I also want to have `Search` model to show up in `User` admin. But also seperately.
how can I register two (or more) `Admins` to `User` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just putting another `Inline` inside the `UserProfileAdmin`, that will then place the `UserProfileInline` and `SearchesInline` in the `UserProfileAdmin`, then put `admin.site.register(Searches)` in `admin.py`. Unless I misunderstand the question.