# how to get all the related objects associated with a User in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I am writing a `Django application` where a User can save "Search".

```
class Searches(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        ....

       def get_searches(self):
           try:
                search_list=Searches.objects.get(user)
           except:
                 return []
           else:
               return search_list.
```

Hence when a User is logged in,
in my view,

```
@login_required
def display_search_list(request):
     user=request.user
     search_list=user.get_searches()
     return render(request,"display.html",{'obj_list':search_list})
```

My question is about `get_searches(self) method` I defined above. 
how can I pass the "currently logged-in User" to get the `search_list`.
All I am interested in is `user.get_searches()` should return all the `saved searches` for that `User`.
how to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@login_required
def display_search_list(request):
    user=request.user
    search_list=Searches.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
    return render(request,"display.html",{'obj_list':search_list})
```

If you need to have a method inside the `Searches` class, I think your signature should be:

```
def get_searches(self, id):
```

But you would need to create an object to call it. I would just build the list in the view.

It does break MVC a little. :) I believe using the `get()` method is for getting one row, to get more than one you should use `filter()`

Comment: Thanks, I will see how it works now. I have another question that is posted here, can you help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720984/how-to-attach-multiple-modeladmins-to-useradmin-in-django

Comment: This is really unnecessary. Django has model back-references just for this.

Answer (score 5):

You have a ForeignKey to the `User` model in `Searches`. So you already have a backreference from *any* user object to all the searches related to that user in this model. For the logged in user, you can call `request.user.searches_set.all()` and it'll return *all* the saved searches for the logged in user. Not sure why you wrote that method. Read more at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships).